# Lazy WPF binding

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding, entity-framework-4

I have `Expander` from WPF (and using Entity Framework 4 and MVVM pattern) which contains `ContentControl` bound to some inner `ViewModel`. All I want is to bind this content control **LAZILY**. That is I want my `ViewModel` to be "get" when the `Expander` is opened.

How to do that? How to make complex windows with inner `ViewModels` faster?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could add an `IsExpanded` property to your ViewModel, bind the expander to it, and take the value of that property into account when returning the content of the `ContentControl`:

```
private bool _isExpanded;
public bool IsExpanded
{
    get { return _isExpanded; }
    set
    {
        _isExpanded = value;
        OnPropertyChange("IsExpanded");
        OnPropertyChange("Content");
    }
}

public SomeType Content
{
    get
    {
        if (!_isExpanded)
            return null;
        return LoadContent();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd cache the content! This way might be calling the LoadContent method many times.

Comment: I added the comment because most of the time you'll want lazy loading because getting the resources is expensive. It wasn't meant as a critique. Just an addition.

Answer (score 0):

Another option similar to the above might be to create an ObservableCollection, but only populate it on the first time the expander is opened.